# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function / body.getScroll is not a function

Tags: jquery, typeerror

I had a working website based on Joomla 3.9.2. But after installing a new component, the below function started to return the error **"Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"** at line **"var body = $(document.body);"**.

```js
((function() {
  var scrollingHeader = function() {
    var body = $(document.body);
    var scroll = body.getScroll();
    if (scroll.y > 0 && body.id !== 'rt-offline' && body.id !== 'rt-comingsoon') body.addClass('scrolling-enable');
    if (scroll.y == 0 && body.hasClass('scrolling-enable')) body.removeClass('scrolling-enable');
  };
  window.addEvent('scroll', scrollingHeader);
})());
```

Searching the Internet I see many posts that the **noConflict** removes the association between $ and jQuery. Indeed I have these lines in my page source, where there is **noConflict** is included:

```html
<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js?941b0fb0b53669f1c7ae375ee879339b" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js?941b0fb0b53669f1c7ae375ee879339b" type="text/javascript"></script>
..
<script src="/media/system/js/mootools-core.js?941b0fb0b53669f1c7ae375ee879339b" type="text/javascript"></script>
..
<script src="/templates/rt_paradigm/js/scrolling-header.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
..
```

Therefore, I changed the error generating line:
**"var body = $(document.body);"**
to this: 
**"var body = jQuery(document.body);"**
But now I get another error:
**Uncaught TypeError: body.getScroll is not a function**
on the line:
**var scroll = body.getScroll();**

So, anyone know how can I resolve the conflict?..

Thanks!

Comment: If jquery-noconflict.js is a version of the jQuery lib then you likely do not want two jQuery

Comment: Reading various sources, I am quite sure that jquery-noconflict.js is not a version of the jQuery. Noconflict seems to be designated to reconnect $ to jQuery after another library is using $ for its own purposes.

Comment: getScroll is neither a jQuery not DOM  method so it must live in scrolling-header

Comment: Yes it does. It is part of the function listed in my question. See the next line after this
var body = $(document.body);

Comment: When you have Joomla questions, feel free to post them at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  This is Rocket Theme's Paradigm, right?

Comment: I can see where `getScroll()` is "called" on `body`, but not where `getScroll()` is "declared` as a function.  Where does the function live in your Joomla build?